# convert a string into array and get values from that array

Tags: php, mysql

i stored an array like {"10":"10","14":"14","16":"16","25":"25"}
this as string in data base, right now i tried to get only number from the above string. I tried with explode and str_replace but i can't get the data, can you please help me.

Comment: 10 10 14 14....or 10 14 16 25?

Answer (score 5):

This is a [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) object you have to decode it with [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) and take its values with [array_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php):

```
$values = array_values(json_decode($string, true));
```